# How to find data-size of a matrix in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pca

I've been given the project of creating facial recognition using *eigenfaces* in C/C++.
Although it uses PCA to greatly reduce the matrix size, before it does that I basically have a matrix of dimension 32,400*32,400 (1.04976e9) and I'd like to write the file-size in my report, if the matrix uses int filetypes will my matrix be of 1.04976e9*4 byte size?

Answer (score 0):

`int` size depends on hardware and compiler.  Its size is `sizeof(int)`.  So your matrix size should be `32400*32400*sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 0):

That's the number of cells, you have to multiply that with the size of integer, `sizeof(int)`, which is typically 4 or 8 bytes.